# an easy way to choose bit(s) form a word

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there an easy way to choose bit(s) form a word ?
I prefer to use with built in library.

For example,
I read the data from binary file (I read 32bit each time because I work with words)
num = 128 (1000 0000 )
I want: num[7:6] = 10 in binary = 2

I did it with ('shift' and 'and') or `int(bin(128)[2:][::-1][6:8][::-1],2)`

Comment: I think slicing is the way as you have done.. haven't seen any standard library offering this functionality..

Comment: I would recommend watching [this](https://youtu.be/F8kx56OZQhg) video. It is a very thorough explanation of bitwise operators and also a very practical guide.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bitwise operators. e.g,
`(((1 << 8) - 1) & num) >> 6`

In general, for bits a to b (higher bits to lower, 0-indexed),
`(((1 << (a+1)) - 1) & num) >> b`

Explanation:
Say num is 121 = `0111 1001`, and we want bit 4 to bit 2 (0-indexed). i.e, `110` or 6. So a = 4, b = 2.
`((1 << (a+1)) - 1)` is just `111...a times`. Doing `&` with this helps us pick the last "a" bits. e.g, any number & `11` will pick its last 2 bits. A number & `111` will pick the last 3 and so on.

So `((1 << (a+1)) - 1) & num` is just the last `a` bits of `num`.
 `>> b` drops the last `b` bits.
Therefore, together,
`(((1 << (a+1)) - 1) & num) >> b` has the effect of picking the last a bits from num, then dropping the last b bits. So together, it will return bits in the `a` to `b` range

Comment: I work with word (not integer). Is it ok ? @Hari Menon

Comment: It should work with word. By the way, my original solution had a bug. Fixed it now. I am adding an explanation.